# GFCI with no loads attached and no downstream outlets trips with power restoration

Tags: gfci

I have recently (purchased 9/18/14) installed several GFCI outlets - Pass & Seymour Legrand - with LED indicating light. I installed three of these - all on separate and dedicated circuits. Upon energizing the breaker(s), every one of the GFCI's tripped when I reset each breaker at the panel. I reset the GFCIs and cycled power at the panel and the same thing happened. At no time did I have a load connected either via the plug-in or to the load side of the GFCI - and I did not wire anything to the line side (except the required leads from the breaker panel box to energize the outlet). Can anyone explain why this is happening - it is not my experience for GFCIs to trip upon power loss and restoration. Thanks.

Comment: So you have two wires? One is attached to one **LINE** screw terminal, and the other is attached to the other **LINE** terminal?  You have the proper wires attached to the proper terminal (e.g. "hot" to brass, "neutral" to silver)?

Comment: Black wire to brass colored terminal side and white wire to silver colored terminal side, ground to green screw. Yes. Black and white attached to LINE, nothing attached to LOAD.

Comment: What is the make and model number of the device? I think some GFCI receptacles go into the trip state when power is lost then restored.

Answer (score 3):

I discussed this concern with the manufacturer (Pass & Seymour by Legrand) and they were able to provide me with a clear answer. The model number is 1595W3PKCC4 - and per design, upon being energized for the first time, these GFCIs are supposed to trip to test themselves. All subsequent cycling of power is not supposed to cause the GFCI to trip. It was my mistake to not validate my observation before posting my question. I have since cycled the power to these devices and they remain in the untripped state upon power restoration - so all is good. Thanks to you folks for your responses. Pass & Seymour was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some (primarily plug-in extension-cord units) that do exactly that, every time power is cycled. I do not know what the expected behavior of the model you bought is - try contacting the manufacturer.

Do they **stay set** (remain powered on) if the breaker is on, and then you reset them? Do they trip if you test them?

Comment: They remain on once reset and trip properly with the TEST button and with a plug-in GFCI tester.